# vsCode setting and switching programming languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using vsCode for coding in python, java, js, and typescript at various times for several years.  But it is always a traumatic experience whenever switching a coding language with vsCode.

I've gotten to the point where I will avoid switching languages because nothing ever works after the switch and it takes loads of time and effort to get things running properly again.  And then the same vsCode problems happen when returning from a short stint in one of the other languages.

What am I missing here?  Should I be doing everything in virtual environments?  Should everything somehow be maintained on GitHub or what?

FYI, the vsCode website explicitly says to request Technical Support of this nature on this Stack website.

[image]

Comment: VS Code should work seamlessly with multiple languages. Can you tell which languages cause you trouble and what kind of trouble?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean – you can use Visual Studio Code to code in multiple different languages at the same time. You mention Java, Javascript, Typescript, and Python in your post – I code in all 4 of those at the same time, and I haven't had any issues.